# QNAP TS-253 pro does not reclaim space after deleting shared folder

Tags: disk-space, shared-folders, qnap

I removed two shared folders from my QNAP (version 4.2) but the space occupied remains the same. I used privilige settings -> shared folders and removed the shared folders. Is there a way to reclaim this space? I emptied the network recycle bin but that didn't work.

I couldn't find any source on Internet but if there is one, please point me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this helps:

From [here](http://docs.qnap.com/nas/4.0/en/index.html?share_folders.htm) -

> To delete a shared folder, select the folder checkbox and click “Remove”. You can select the option “Also delete the data. (Mounted ISO image files will not be deleted)” to delete the folder and the files in it. If you select not to delete the folder data, the data will be retained in the NAS. You can create a shared folder of the same name again to access the data.

Previous link was for version 4.0, this is for [version 4.2](http://docs.qnap.com/nas/4.2/Home/en/index.html), but it looks about the same procedure in case there are subtle changes from my last link.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've been saved already since this thread is from '15. But just go to FileStation on your QNAP and open the Recycle Bin. Delete the files you deleted from the share. That's it!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's good to know. But first one has to remove the data and that was the checkbox I overlooked which was pointed out to me by Jonno.